# Bayesian equivalent of the frequentist test of equal or given proportions

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test, frequentist

I am interested in comparing the prevalence of common mental disorders (CMDs) such as posttraumatic stress disorder (PTSD), anxiety, and depression.

I would like to know whether the prevalence I obtained (Prev. 1) calculated with `High * 100 / N` is statistically different from the prevalence obtained by the WHO (Prev. 2).

I have the following table where N, Low, and High are dummy data generated with some R code (`Prev 2 (%)` numbers are real, though; WHO, 2017, 2013):

```
       N Low High Prev. 1 (%) Prev. 2 (%) X.Squared df p.Value
PTSD 331 164  167       50.45         3.6  2080.279  1       0
ANX  313 157  156       49.84         4.4  1525.655  1       0
DEP  324 168  156       48.15         3.6  1839.970  1       0
```

The frequentist calculations involved is the test of equal or given proportion. What is the Bayesian equivalent of that test?

---

For reproducibility purposes, please find the R code used to generate the table above:

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate random data
n <- 490
PTSD <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE)
ANX <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE)
DEP <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), n, replace = TRUE)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(PTSD, ANX, DEP) #class(df) = "data.frame"

# Label the values: 1 = Low, 2 = High
expss::val_lab(df$PTSD) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")
expss::val_lab(df$ANX) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")
expss::val_lab(df$DEP) = expss::num_lab("1 Low
                                        2 High")

# Create a list of tables for each variable to count 1s, 2s, and NAs
count_results <- list(
  PTSD = table(df$PTSD, useNA = "ifany"),
  ANX = table(df$ANX, useNA = "ifany"),
  DEP = table(df$DEP, useNA = "ifany")
)

# Combine the count tables into a single table
count_table <- do.call(rbind, count_results)

# Initialize empty vectors to store results
variable_names <- character()
sample_sizes <- numeric()

# Loop through the test results and extract relevant information
for (variable_name in names(count_results)) {
  sample_sizes <- c(sample_sizes, sum(count_results[[variable_name]]))
  variable_names <- c(variable_names, variable_name)
}

# Create summary data frame
summary_df <- data.frame(
  N = sample_sizes,
  Variable = variable_names
)

# Combine the count table and chi-squared summary table by columns
final_result <- cbind(count_table, summary_df)

# Remove Variable column in the middle of the table
final_result <- subset(final_result, select = -c(Variable))

# Remove the NA column
final_result <- final_result[, -3]

# Calculate the N column and add it before the Low column
final_result$N <- final_result$Low + final_result$High
final_result <- cbind(final_result, 3)[, c(3, 1, 2)]

# Calculate the Prevalence column
final_result$Prevalence <- round(final_result$High / final_result$N * 100, 2)

# Add the WHO column
W_data <- c(3.6, 4.4, 3.6)
final_result$W <- W_data

# Rename the columns
colnames(final_result) <- c("N", "Low", "High", "Prev. 1 (%)", "Prev. 2 (%)")

# Add Chi-squared stats columns to final_result table
#****************************************************

# Initialize empty vectors to store results
chi_squared_values <- numeric()
df_values <- numeric()
p_values <- numeric()

# Loop through each row of the final_result data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(final_result)) {
  # Extract counts from the current row
  N_i <- final_result[i, "N"]
  count_low_i <- final_result[i, "Low"]
  count_high_i <- final_result[i, "High"]
  expected_proportion_w <- final_result[i, "Prev. 2 (%)"] / 100
  
  # Observed proportion for generated data
  observed_proportion_i <- count_high_i / N_i
  
  # Perform a proportion test
  prop_test_result <- prop.test(x = count_high_i, n = N_i, p = expected_proportion_w)
  
  # Store results in the vectors
  chi_squared_values <- c(chi_squared_values, prop_test_result$statistic)
  df_values <- c(df_values, prop_test_result$parameter)
  p_values <- c(p_values, prop_test_result$p.value)
}

# Add the calculated values to the final_result data frame
final_result$X.Squared <- chi_squared_values
final_result$df <- df_values
final_result$p.Value <- p_values

# Print the updated table
print(final_result)
```

References

- World Health Organization [WHO]. (2017). *Depression and other common mental disorders: Global health estimates* (WHO/MSD/MER/2017.2; p. 22). World Health Organization. https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/254610/WHO-MSD-MER-2017.2-eng.pdf
- World Health Organization [WHO]. (2013). *WHO releases guidance on mental health care after trauma*. WHO; World Health Organization. https://www.who.int/mediacentre/news/releases/2013/trauma_mental_health_20130806/en/